# Is it posible to split path route in .conf file?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

Im am trying to code this .conf file with more scalability, and my idea is to, in order to have multi index in elasticsearch, split the path and get the last position to have the csv name and set it to the type and index in elasticsearch.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

input {
  file {
    path => "/home/aitor2/RETO8/BIGDATA/df_suministro_activa.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
  file {
    path => "/home/aitor2/RETO8/BIGDATA/df_activo_consumo.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
}
path2 = path.split('/')[-1]
filter {
if [path] == "/home/aitor2/RETO8/BIGDATA/df_suministro_activa.csv"{
    mutate { replace => { type => path2 } } 
  csv {
      separator => ","
      skip_header => "true"
      autodetect_column_names => true
  }
     ruby {
    code => "event.to_hash.each { |k, v|
    if k.start_with?('Linea') and v.is_a?(String)
      event.set(k, v.to_f)
    end
}
  "
}
  
}
else if [path] == "/home/aitor2/RETO8/BIGDATA/df_activo_consumo.csv"{
    mutate { replace => { type => "apaches2" } } 
  csv {
      separator => ","
      skip_header => "true"
      autodetect_column_names => true
  }
   ruby {
    code => "event.to_hash.each { |k, v|
    if k.start_with?('Smart') and v.is_a?(String)
      event.set(k, v.to_f)
    end
}
  "
}
  
 }



}

output {
   elasticsearch {
     hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
     index => "%{type}_indexer"
 }
  
stdout {codec => rubydebug}

}
```

I tried to do it with `path2 = path.split('/')[-1]` but im not sure it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `filter` part, set the value of `type` to the filename (`df_suministro_activa.csv` or `df_activo_consumo.csv`). I use `grok` for this ; `mutate` is another possibility [(cf doc)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html).

You can then use `type` in the output / in the if-else / change its value, etc.

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/home/aitor2/RETO8/BIGDATA/df_suministro_activa.csv"
    ...
  }
  file {
    path => "/home/aitor2/RETO8/BIGDATA/df_activo_consumo.csv"
    ...
  }
}

filter {
  grok { match { "path" => "UNIXPATH/(?<type>[^/]+)" } }

  if [type] == "df_suministro_activa.csv" {
    ...
  }
  else if [type] == "df_activo_consumo.csv" {
    mutate { replace => { type => "apaches2" } } 
    ...
  }
}

output {
   elasticsearch {
     hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
     index => "%{type}_indexer"
  }
}
```

I am unsure about the `path` field ; you may want to try `[log][file][path]` instead of `path` in the `filter` block.